# Fetching query results with PostgreSQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to get my postgresql to work. I've worked with sql before, but never postgres.

I feel like the following should display a nice table of outputs.

I've tested the php in several places, and it seems that the result variable is not getting anything returned, and so is a boolean of false value, so there's nothing retreived. If anyone could help me find the error I'd be grateful.

```
if($queryType != NULL)

    echo'<table>;
    if($limit == NULL && $offset == NULL)
    {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM $1';
    $stmt = pg_prepare($connection, "limitoffset", $query);
    $result = pg_execute($connection, "limitoffset", array($queryType));

    if($queryType == 'city'){
    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $row['id] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
 echo '</table>';
```

again, it compiles and runs, but it seems $row is coming back as false after the query, and so the loop is not running to print out the results, because it has none.

thanks!

Comment: You are missing a closing ' after echo '<table>;  Is this just on SO or in your code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a placeholder for an identifier (i.e. table or column name) so this:

```
select * from $1
```

won't work. If you want the table name to be a variable, I think you're stuck with string interpolation:

```
$table = pg_escape_identifier($queryType);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
```

You'll want to use [`pg_escape_identifier`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) to avoid problems with strange values in `$queryType` but keep in mind that `pg_escape_identifier` will double quote the identifier and that could give you case sensitivity problems.

You also have two missing single quotes in your question: one in `echo'<table>;` and another in `. $row['id] .` but those are presumably just in your question text since you say that the code compiles and runs.